# Initialize SNSEvent.java with SNS Event String

Tags: amazon-s3, events

I'm working with an in-house framework to consume S3Events. The current framework can handle plain S3EventNotifications by getting the events InputStream, and passing it like below...

```
String inputStream = CharStreams.toString( new InputStreamReader(eventInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
S3EventNotification s3EventNotification = S3EventNotification.parseJson(inputStream);
```

For technical reasons, I now need to update this framework to use SNS Events, which are quite different from a raw JSON perspective. I'm hoping to find an SNSEvent equivelant of S3EventNotification so I can do something like below...

```
String inputStream = CharStreams.toString( new InputStreamReader(eventInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
SNSEvent snsEvent = SomethingGoesHere.parseJson(inputStream);
```

Is there anything like that out there? I've looked through a few of the aws-java-sdk's as well as the aws-lambda-java-events artifacts out there in Maven world but can't seem to find anything suitable to this. Any ideas?

**EDIT With Solution**

Ended up settling with the SNSEvent.java object located in the aws-lambda-java-events jar from Maven. I used Gson with a DateTime adapter to handle the DateTime Timestamp within that object as well as the UPPER_CAMEL_CASE naming policy since the SNS Event from amazon is camel cased, seems to work fine!

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
        .registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<DateTime>() {

            @Override
            public DateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                    throws JsonParseException {
                return new DateTime(json.getAsString());
            }
        }).create();

    SNSEvent snsEvent = gson.fromJson(event, SNSEvent.class);
```

Comment: Found a way, edited original post with an example